# Import a selfcalling function from an npm module into a react/webpack app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've build a react app transpiled with webpack and now want to use a package pulled from npm (namely [vanilla-cookieconsent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-cookieconsent)). Alas, it's written pretty old school, there is no export or nothing, instead it's just a self calling function that adds a method to the window object. And for the life of me I can't seem to get it into my react/webpack combo.

So, what is the correct way to load and use such a function in a transpiled react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't simply something like

```
import '~vanilla-cookieconsent/cookieconsent.css';

...

useEffect(() => {
  import('~vanilla-cookieconsent/cookieconsent.js').then(() => {
    // Loading the script should have injected this to window
    window.cookieconsent.run(...);
  });
}, []);
```

do the trick?

Comment: Will give it a try.